# cmake external project: allow either download or user-specified path

Tags: cmake

Consider a project which depends on an external project. When configuring my project, I'd like to offer the user one of two choices:

- allow cmake's ExternalProject tool to automatically download, configure, build, and install this external project
- allow the user to manually specify the paths to headers/libs if the external project has already been locally built

The idea is that, if the user doesn't care and just runs

```
cmake .
```

then cmake would automatically perform the download and install of the external project. However, it's common for a developer to already have the external project built locally on his machine (and not installed). In order to save memory or for ease of customization, I'd also like to the user to be able to manually specify (through ccmake for instance) the header and library paths for that project, which would save cmake the effort of downloading and compiling.

Is there a neat way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about a neat way, but it's possible.  I'd imagine the rough flow would be something like:

```
add_executable(Foo ...)

find_path(OtherProjectIncludes NAMES ...)
find_library(OtherProjectLib NAMES ...)

if(OtherProjectIncludes AND OtherProjectLib)
  include_directories(${OtherProjectIncludes})
  target_link_libraries(Foo ${OtherProjectLib})
else()
  include(ExternalProject)
  ...
endif()
```

If there's a FindModule available for the other project, you'd presumably use `find_package` in place of `find_path` and `find_library`.

Regardless, you'd need to decide how to handle the case where the user passes a path with the intention of finding an existing (built) copy of the other project, but the `find_xxx` calls fail.  You could go on to invoke the `ExternalProject` module, or you could provide a helpful `FATAL_ERROR` message and allow the user to retry.